# How to take a beating from a bully?

Tags: self-defense, self-training, bullying

I was wondering how to take a beating from someone who trains in MMA and Wrestling. There is this guy at my job who regularly follows me home and beats me. I need to know how to take this punishment like a man so maybe he'll stop. How do I take a beating? P.S. My beating normally takes the shape of 100's of punches, kicks, and anytime I try to hit back he just blocks or dodges them. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Is calling the police an option in your part of the world?

Comment: I don't want to be a baby.

Comment: If I call the police his buddies will just beat me up worse.

Comment: Yeah, this is criminal assault. “Taking punishment like a man?” That’s ridiculous. Although if it’s “100s of punches and kicks” I question either his skill or intent.

Comment: I don't know if there is a single answer that any one of us could give you here. All martial arts training takes time, so you can't expect to get a solve-all answer by asking the internet. Since it seems like you need help as soon as possible, I would recommend contacting the authorities and also telling your employer, since you said he works with you.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome, Mike.

It is *NOT* 'being a baby' to ask for help in your situation. Being victimised in this way can be a horrible, distressing experience. You don't deserve to be going through it.

*You need help, and the smartest thing for you to do is to seek help. There is absolutely no shame in this.*

You don't have to answer the following questions, but if you do, it may be possible to provide you with some more specific advice, including a range options for seeking help.

Are you deemed an adult in your country/state/province?

Which country/province/state do you live in?

What support networks (family/friends/acquaintances/colleagues) do you have access to?

Can you remove yourself from the situation, either by changing jobs or by changing the times you go to and from work?

Contrary to one of the previous answers, it may not be wise you arm yourself, as any weapons you try to use may well be used against you, especially if you lack skills and are afraid of your attacker (as you have every right to be). Producing a weapon may also provoke more severe attacks.

You will likely be able to resolve this situation eventually, but simply waiting for the abuse to stop may result in you suffering more harm than necessary. Hang in there.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this guy is using you as a wooden dummy, and that he does not intend to hurt you (given the information that you are still able to type after receiving 100's of punches and kicks from him). With this in mind, you can try to fight back as fast and as hard as possible. The essential thing would be not to lose confidence so that you can continue fighting if no serious injuries occur. You can also try to carry a tactical pen with you, for that it is an amazingly capable weapon for people with a bit of martial arts training.

Consider learning parkour if you are fit enough to do so. Parkour should help you get rid of any untrained pursuers.

But, still, the ideal way to solve this is to call the police (and inform them that you will get beaten up worse if the suspect knew you called them). If you live in a country with up-to-standard police forces, then you should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to remind you that if you think that the life of you or others is in danger, do not try to take the threat on by yourself. Get to a safe place and call the police.

But if you are cornered, and there is absolutely no other option, you may have to fight. I'm only a white belt right now, but I know a few things that I would trust a person to use to protect me if I were in your position. Here are a few basic kajukenbo moves that I know:

punch 1. Punch one is a normal nothing special move with your left hand. Try to place it in the stomach or face. Punch 2. Punch 2 is a punch 1 but with your right hand. Punch 3 is basically where you strike the side of your target, either on the side of the head or on the side of the body with your left hand. Punch 4 is an uppercut with your right hand.

Kicks are very simple. Basic: Just kick! But be sure to keep your block up at all times. Also be sure to hit them with your heel and not your toe.

Sidekick: No, not like robin. A sidekick is where you take a sideways fighting stance and kick to your side at or near the bully's stomach.

Roundhouse: I'm sure you've heard of this one before. Like a sidekick, but you keep yourself at the forward and rotate your body to move your leg with it. Be sure to turn your leg sideways when you do this, as striking somebody using your hamstring will likely not be a pleasant experience, and it won't actually do much. Use a tough part of your shin.

Groin: quick sidenote, this is the ONLY kick that I know of where it is acceptable to strike with the top of your foot, for all other kicks unless an instructor tells you otherwise, use your heel. A groin kick is exactly what it sounds like (Works best if you're wearing a boot). A groin kick will inflict a lot of pain and I feel sorry for anyone who was on the wrong end of one. Use the top of your foot and strike upwards.

Alright, pay close attention to this part, as it may save your life one day. Blocks. What I've said so far is telling you how to kick butt, but from what you've said, you probably need more advice on what to do when you're getting your butt kicked.

Guard: You should be doing this the entire fight anyway. Hold both hands above your jaw but just below your eyes so you can see. Only take your hands away from your face if you are attempting to strike, as soon as you are done, return to your guarding position.

Block 1: Counter an oncoming punch by taking it with the side of your left arm. Then offset the bully's arm away from you and hold it there, then hit 'em with a punch 2.

Block 2: Block 1, but with your right arm, and end with punch 1.

Block 3 (body block): Position one of your arms to cover your entire lower body while keeping your other arm in guard. This can be used to take a kick or if your opponent also uses kajukenbo or another martial art, it can also be used to counter block 1/2 or punch 1/2.

Now I'd like you to remember that fighting should be your absolute last resort. Only do so if you think you are in real danger and the police will not arrive in time to stop them from killing you. It is true the police will usually arrest anyone and everyone involved in a fight (guilt by association) including the one who was being attacked. While I believe this system is flawed, it is how it is, and I can't change that. You mentioned that he may beat you harder if you call the police, but if you call them again, he will probably go to prison for repeat offences if not immediately for criminal assault.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to stop people like this is to hurt them badly enough that they will leave you alone, and if you really think his friends will be a problem you need to hurt him enough to scare them.

It would probably violate the Code Of Conduct to give more explicit advice.